# Linux English German Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, reference-request

Is there any offline dictionary with the following qualities out there?

Required Features:

- pronunciation of the words
- multiple examples of the word usage with pronunciation as well
- thesaurus
- word gender
- word type (noun, verb, adverb, adjective)
- word frequency

Optional

- idioms
- grammar guidelines
- irregular verbs
- minimal pairs

Comment: What parameters define 'the best' to you?

Comment: What parameters define "available" to you? Do you mean for free? Or a dictionary software product available for money from an established publishing house?

Comment: @Marzipanherz free, with pronunciation, examples, thesaurus and all the rudimentary functionalities of a dictionary.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann free would be better.

Comment: @pouya could you please edit your question and add the relevant specifications there? A question here should be self-contained and include all information and details, since comments might get deleted in near future (and no-one likes to read through a wall of comments to gather all details).

Comment: Apart from the fact that I’m not at all sure there are all that many such dictionaries out there, asking for **the best** is heavily opinion-based, and I vote to close this question for that reason.

Comment: @Philipp Features was there when you saw the question . Anyway got rid of the evil BEST word. I hope now it complies with the community standards.

Comment: Shall the word Linux signal for a compatible software or is it a marker for a free license? A dictionary could be stored in a file format without any software, which makes me wonder a bit, what it is what is asked for.

Comment: @userunknown it signals the both. What do you mean by "A dictionary could be stored in a file format without any software" something like a PDF file? or a word list?

Comment: Pronouncation is very easy on German, more exactly there is a nearly direct relation between the written and spoken form of the words. This is why you don't need to find it, like on English. Although learning it might be hard if it is alien for your first language. It is also hard to comprehend it, they like to "abbreviate" the spoken forms and there are large pronouncation differences also in the dialects.

Comment: @peterh to me German grammar (words gender) and the way characters are pronounced are strange. It is my third language and i'm kind of nervous about pronunciation cause there is no native speaker around and in the absence of a valid offline resource, bad habits can grow rapidly. As a German speaker how do you evaluate TTS Engines and Google translate, are they reliable?

Comment: @pouya I don't know TTS. Google translate is bad, alone it is not useful for translating sentences! Learn the grammar, it is very beautiful and logical. English-German google translate is far better than any other to and from German. And expand it with tricky searches. I typically verify the google translate results with google image search (it works mainly for nouns) or with simple google search (I search for the result, and check their exact meaning in the result). I use also Thunderbird for mails, it has a nice spellchecker.

Comment: @peterh thanks so you are not a native speaker just like me.  For grammar what is a brief,  to the point and non-nonsense resource to get me up and running fast? Anyway these comments are going to hit some red lines i guess:).

Comment: @pouya Maybe you could buy a book... but maybe a wiki could be also written.

Comment: @pouya: I think about a file format like CSV or XML, where the items of your list appear in a specified order (CSV) or in a tagged way (XML), not something like a PDF which specifies the layout.

Comment: @userunknown yeah i thought the same. Actually dict.cc wordlist can  be [downloaded](https://www1.dict.cc/translation_file_request.php?l=e) as a tab-separated UTF-8 text file. I'm trying to comprehend how data is compiled but cause i haven't used dict.cc before it is kinda hard and be aware, the file is formatted using UNIX line endings. Download the file and take a look maybe that's what you need. That is all i have on my machine:)

Comment: @userunknown Do you have a better compiled wordlist with meaning, examples, IPA, type, ... in a format which is suited to parsing like XML or JSON?

Comment: @pouya: It's not me who is in need for such a file. If I was, UNIX line endings would be what I was looking for, since I'm almost exclusively working on Linux. There are other wordlists on Linux programs; I remember the programs Steak/XSteak with an FOSS licensed word table, but it only fits very few of your needs. Maybe it is still available - I've used it about 20 years ago today, (Sgt. Pepper told the band to play ...)

Comment: @pouya: No, I don't have such a file, only the wordlist of Steak/XSteak (which seems to be an abandoned program) with entries like "(Interessen, Rechte) wahrnehmen :: to protect, to safeguard" which is more a CSV-Format, one phrase per line, DE/ENG delimited by "::", Alternatives delimited by comma, available here: http://freshmeat.sourceforge.net/projects/xsteak

Answer (score 2):

It does not have all the required features, but still a lot:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=livio.pack.lang.de_DE&hl=en_US

And you can download the list from dict.cc

https://www1.dict.cc/translation_file_request.php?l=e

Comment: Thanks although the question is about a Linux solution but an android dictionary is appreciated too.